# setOnClickListener unknown error

Tags: android, eclipse

hi guys im trying to make an ActionBar for my test app but when i use setOnClickListener for my button i faced to this error:

> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

help me plz!

```
    import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.*;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Button btn;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ActionBar mActionBar=getActionBar();

        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mlnflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View mCustomView=mlnflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar,null);
        TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        mTitleTextView.setText("HESAB");
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the whole stack trace look like?

Comment: it is a compile time error, what do you expect in the logcat?

Comment: Have you imported View.OnClickListener?

Comment: i cant run my app to see logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
});
```

with this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
});
```

The error clearly states, that `setOnClickListener` method expects the instance of `View.OnClickListener` type.

Comment: @mehdiakbarian if you have another crash - it is another issue. the current issue which is listed in your question is resolved.

Comment: yea but your change make my app crash!if i delete your change and btn codes app run correctly!

Comment: @mehdiakbarian take a look at the logcat for the crash source. I bet it is `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // Do some job here

    }
});
```

Comment: simply  import android.view.View; and its a default when you create a activity

Comment: save your project and clean  also then run it.